# Deleting certain integers from string list

Tags: list-manipulation, string-manipulation

I have a list of strings:

```
lis = {"a","1","b","2","c","3","a","d","4"}
```

and would like to get:

```
res = {"a","b","2","c","3","a","d","4"}
```

where each occurrence of `"a"` that is immediately followed by (a string representation of) an integer, that integer is deleted from the list.  `ToExpression` followed by `IntegerQ` seems inefficient, would be grateful for thoughts.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`SequenceReplace`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SequenceReplace.html):

```
SequenceReplace[lis, {"a", _?(StringMatchQ[NumberString])} :> "a"]
```

> {"a", "b", "2", "c", "3", "a", "d", "4"}

Also

```
SequenceReplace[lis, {"a", _?(IntegerQ @* ToExpression)} :> "a"]
```

> {"a", "b", "2", "c", "3", "a", "d", "4"}

[`Split`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Split.html) + [`ReplaceAll`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html)

```
Flatten[Split[lis, # == "a" &] /. {"a", _?(IntegerQ@*ToExpression) } :> "a"]
```

> {"a", "b", "2", "c", "3", "a", "d", "4"}

Answer (score 6):

The following works for your example. But I am not sure that it will work for you if your example is not descriptive enough for some more general situation you have in mind.

```
lis = {"a", "1", "b", "2", "c", "3", "a", "d", "4"};
Flatten[Partition[lis, UpTo[2]] /. {"a", "1"} -> "a"]
```

> ```
> {"a", "b", "2", "c", "3", "a", "d", "4"}
> ```

Answer (score 3):

```
list = {"a", "1", "b", "2", "c", "3", "a", "3", "d", "4", "a", "9"};
```

Pre-define pattern for better readability

```
p = _?(StringMatchQ @ NumberString);
```

**1.**

With `SequenceSplit` (new in 11.3)

```
SequenceSplit[list, {"a", p} :> "a"]
```

{"a", {"b", "2", "c", "3"}, "a", {"d", "4"}, "a"}

```
Flatten[%]
```

{"a", "b", "2", "c", "3", "a", "d", "4", "a"}

**2.**

With `SequencePosition` (new in 10.1)

```
SequencePosition[list, {"a", p}] /. {_, a_} :> {a}
```

{{2}, {8}, {12}}

```
Delete[%] @ list
```

{"a", "b", "2", "c", "3", "a", "d", "4", "a"}

Answer (score 2):

The input list is slightly modified to test for the case where only integers following "a" are removed.

```
lis = {"a", "1", "b", "2", "c", "3", "a", "1.4", "d", "4", "a", "2"};
```

**Using `PatternSequence`** and **`ReplaceRepeated`:**

```
lis //. {x___, PatternSequence["a", k_String], y___} /; 
   IntegerQ[ToExpression[k]] :> {x, "a", y}
```

or equivalently:

```
lis //. {x___, PatternSequence["a", _String?(IntegerQ@*ToExpression)],
    y___} :> {x, "a", y}
```

**Using `SequencePosition`** and **`Delete`:**

```
Delete[lis,  List /@ Last /@     SequencePosition[lis, {"a",
_?(IntegerQ@*ToExpression)}]  ]
```

---

*Result*

> {"a", "b", "2", "c", "3", "a", "1.4", "d", "4", "a"}

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {"a", "1", "b", "2", "c", "3", "a", "3", "d", "4", "a", "9"};
```

Grabbing the @eldo's list and using `ReplaceRepeated`:

```
list //. {r___, k : "a", n_?DigitQ, b___String, s___} :> {r, k, b, s}

(*{"a", "b", "2", "c", "3", "a", "d", "4", "a"}*)
```

Or using `Delete` and `Position`:

```
Delete[#, Function[p, p + 1]@Position[#, "a"]] &@list

(*{"a", "b", "2", "c", "3", "a", "d", "4", "a"}*)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {"a", "1", "b", "2", "c", "3", "a", "d", "4"};

Last /@ BlockMap[Replace[{"a", "1"} -> {"a"}], list, 2, 1]
```

{"a", "b", "2", "c", "3", "a", "d", "4"}